# Space issue in Solr

Tags: solr

Consider if the disk space(Physical memory) is about 1GB and the data index from the DB is about 1GB.

In future if the data in DB grows then indexing the data also grows inside solr. How to handle the memory leakage in solr.

We can group the distributed index data from different location by using **"shard"** parameter in solr.

Here my question is **how to share the index data to another location** during run time? /
How to split the index data to different location during run time? Is there any possibility to achieve this in solr.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate data to another location using [SolrReplication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication)

Even if index is bigger than memory available to Solr instance there is no problem to use it. I don't think the index is in the memory whole the time as a whole, that could not be possible. Index I'm working with is ~10G while memory available for Solr is significantly less.

As for adding new shards/splitting data, during run time, I honestly do not know is it possible (by bet is on "It's not possible"). [DistributedSearch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) wiki page mentions need of reindexing to move data to specific shard.

Comment: Thanks Fuxi. I think in this case we need to shard/split the index data manually with different solr server. While query we will use shard parameter to search among different server. I hope it is the only way to do.

Comment: If you have real need to sharding your index, Solr's wiki http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud and mentioned above http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch should help. Do you use DIH or you're posting items to Solr?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Currently using 'Solr 3.6', may be SolrCloud useful once 'Solr 4.0 BETA' officially released. Currently using DIH we are fetching the result from DB.

Comment: I have been released last week :D http://searchhub.org/dev/2012/10/12/apache-solr-and-lucene-4-0-0-released/